# Do you get into olam haba if you do not celebrate shabbat, eat pig, basically disregard Judaism?

Tags: olam-haba-world-to-come, non-religious

Do you? I mean like do nothing?

Comment: [הקדמת הרמב"ם לפרק חלק](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/mahshevt/rambam/hakdamat-2.htm)

Comment: What would you be rewarded for?

Comment: If you die Al Kiddush Hashem yes. 
Q: "How is it that someone that ate treif, was michalel Shabbos, doesn’t believe in the Torah gets olam haba if he dies Al Kiddush Hashem?"
A: "I was in a group that asked about this to Rav Shmuel Kaminetzky right after the Dolphinarium bombing. He said that’s how it is [DJB: On 1 June 2001, a Hamas Jihadi blew himself up outside the Dolphinarium disco in Tel Aviv, Israel, killing 21 Jews, 16 of whom were teenagers] " https://www.theyeshivaworld.com/coffeeroom/topic/dying-al-kiddush-hashem#post-886311

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya Joshua and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: See Talmud Bavli Rosh Hashana 17a.

Comment: I don't know if anyone can say for sure who does and doesn't get into Olam Haba except Hashem, but I always get a bit annoyed when people say that they "keep nothing".  I don't think it is possible to not keep any mitzvos. I don't think anyone goes through life with no conscience or concern for doing the right thing.  Even people who "keep nothing" in practice probably do a lot.  It is also about how far they have come from where they have started and the challenges they face. eg.If they have grown up in an environment where keeping mitzvos is not normal, it isn't the same as someone who has.

Comment: @Schmerel This isn’t me, I am asking more as a concept.

Comment: @Deuteronomy I am unable to read Hebrew

Comment: @Joshua here is an English translation: [Maimonides Introduction to Perek Helek](https://www.mhcny.org/qt/1005.pdf)

Comment: Even if they got Olam Haba, what would they do with it?